# Why do `login` and `sudo` fork a child process, and not exec() straight away?

Tags: sudo, login

When I ran a long-running command under `sudo`, I noticed that `sudo` showed up in the process list (`ps`).

At the same time I noticed `login` shows up in `systemctl status "session-${XDG_SESSION_ID}.scope"` when you log in on the text console.

Why do they fork a separate child process?  Why do they not use `exec()` which would entirely replace themselves, with the desired program (a shell, in the case of `login`)?  That's how `nice` and `env` work, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent process has stuff to clean up afterwards.  E.g. for the login records, see `man utmp` which is used for commands like `who` to show the list of logged in users.

On Linux, both the setup and cleanup actions are performed by Pluggable Authentication Modules (PAM).

Comment: … which is why, of course, [one should not abuse `su` for dropping privileges](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dont-abuse-su-for-dropping-privileges.html).

Comment: @JdeBP lol, though I don't think the argument is very clear there, the single point with "temporary network mounts" is far more convincing :).  You might be happy to know that `man su` on my machine points you right towards yet another minimal wrapper, `setpriv`, which is part of util-linux.  I don't see it in Debian Jessie though, only Fedora.